# Why does my DynDNS domain show the router page, not the localhost?

Tags: router, routing, home-server

I have to setup a home server. I have created a DynDNS account and updated the software.

I have set the dynamic dns option in router and while I ping my dyndns account it is redirecting to my router page and not to the localhost.

My router is a Starcom WA3002G4.

Answer (score 2):

Few routers honor port forwarding rules when the source is within the LAN. Configure your browser to use a proxy on the Internet for your network then try again.

Answer (score 2):

You need to port forward the ports you want accessible to the outside world (probably port 80).

Answer (score 1):

Have you configured the router to forward traffic to the server?  I don't know how to do it on youre router, but it shouldn't be particularly difficult.  Some routers allow the creation of a "DMZ" or have built in processed for publishing to the internet.

Comment: +1 - i Agree i think its a port forwarding issue.